# Reading in a .geojson file with geojsonio, geojsonR

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial, geojson, r-sf

I am trying to read in a geojson file (https://www.svz-bw.de/fileadmin/verkehrszentrale/RadNETZ-BW_Daten_GeoJSON_2018-20.zip) in R.

I have tried different packages but my knowledge is too limited to find the errors and solve them. Im new to spatial data in R, especially reading geojson file format.
Googling and searching in stackoverflow hasnt helped.

`geojsonR::FROM_geojson("../Sonstiges/RadNETZ.geojson")`

> Error in unlink(x) : file name conversion problem -- name too long?

`geojsonR::FROM_GeoJson("../Sonstiges/RadNETZ.geojson")`

> Error in export_From_geojson(url_file_string, Flatten_Coords,
> Average_Coordinates,  :    invalid GeoJson geometry object -->
> geom_OBJ() function

Comment: Really want to use R and not Qgis?

Comment: I need the data in R later on anyways for statistical analysis. Just trying to extract joint distributions from this data and weight them based on the length of the paths (which are bike lanes btw) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file does not comply with the current GeoJSON standards; it uses a projected coordinate reference system, which goes against RFC 7946 -  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-12

This may, and may not, be the reason why geojson specific packages have hard time interpreting it.

In order to process your file I suggest using {sf}, which is - via GDAL and PROJ - able to digest the file.

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

asdf <- st_read("RadNETZ.geojson") %>% 
  st_transform(4326) # safety of unprojected CRS

plot(st_geometry(asdf))
```

[image: radnetz file contents]

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will forward this info to the Official Office releasing the data.
Are the calculations of length of the paths accurate, if I calculate using this projection?

Comment: "Accurate" is a slippery term  in order to maximize consistency with other results you may want to drop the st_transform(4326) part. The data will behave less like true GeoJSONs, but the lengths will be more in line with the projected CRS your data came in.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jindra Lacko mentioned your 'RadNETZ.geojson' file does not comply with the RFC 7946 that's why you receive the error. If you don't have GDAL installed on your Operating System besides the 'sf' package you can use either the [geojsonR::shiny_from_JSON](https://mlampros.github.io/geojsonR/reference/shiny_from_JSON.html) (which does not follow the RFC and is meant to be used in shiny applications),

```
dat = geojsonR::shiny_from_JSON("../Sonstiges/RadNETZ.geojson")
str(dat)

List of 4
 $ crs     :List of 2
  ..$ properties:List of 1
  .. ..$ name: chr "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31467"
  ..$ type      : chr "name"
 $ features:List of 70097
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ geometry  :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ coordinates:List of 6
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 3563993
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 5353055
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 3564002
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 5353070
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 3564009
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 5353087
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 3564013
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 5353103
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 3564016
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 5353109
  .. .. .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 3564030
  .. .. .. .. ..$ : num 5353121
  .. .. ..$ type       : chr "LineString"
  .. ..$ properties:List of 24
  .....
```

or the [jsonlite::fromJSON](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/jsonlite.pdf) function,

```
dat = jsonlite::fromJSON("../Sonstiges/RadNETZ.geojson")
str(dat)

List of 4
 $ type    : chr "FeatureCollection"
 $ name    : chr "sql_statement"
 $ crs     :List of 2
  ..$ type      : chr "name"
  ..$ properties:List of 1
  .. ..$ name: chr "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31467"
 $ features:'data.frame':   70097 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ type      : chr [1:70097] "Feature" "Feature" "Feature" "Feature" ...
  ..$ properties:'data.frame':  70097 obs. of  24 variables:
  .. ..$ gid     : int [1:70097] 4 15 23 22 45 72 60 74 13072 75 ...
  .. ..$ lrvn_kat: int [1:70097] 3 1 1 3 1 1 3 1 3 1 ...
  .....
```

For the record I'm the author / maintainer of the [geojsonR](https://github.com/mlampros/geojsonR) package